# Unmet dependency while installing cnijfilter-mp550series package

Tags: 14.04, apt

I've been using my Canon MP550 printer for some Ubuntu versions now, and installation always worked:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk  
$ sudo apt-get update  
$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp550series
```

However, with a fresh 14.04 install I get this unmet dependency problem:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming. The following information may  to
resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  cnijfilter-mp550series: i386: Depends: libtiff4: i386 (> 3. 9. 5-3~) but
  it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
  broken packages.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

14.04 provides [libtiff5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libtiff5) but not [libtiff4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libtiff4) (up to saucy 13.10).

To install the 13.10 version, go to the i386 download [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libtiff4/download) and select a mirror to get `libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb`.

Now open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type in the folder where you downloaded the deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

You can now install your printer drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp550series
```

Comment: Oh, hallelujah!  I have been trying to fix my printer for over a week. I did not get any error messages but installing this library also makes the drivers for the Canon MF8200C Series work.

Comment: Good to know, thanks Ron. Please up-vote if my answer helped you

Comment: Sorry about that, I always try to upvote useful questions and answers.

Comment: You should never have to install package from other repositories.

Comment: I'm afraid the [donwload page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libtiff4) has expired. But [this one in old-releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/) saved my day.